# Python Shapely point lies within a polygon but not within the polygon boundary

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, geopandas

I am trying to find if a point (lon,lat) lies inside a country. I am using following code to get a polygon of a country and check whether a point lies within the polygon:

```
 def country_polygon(country_name):
     country_name = country_name.title()
     world        = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

     if country_name in world.name.values:
        country_map = world.loc[world.name == "{}".format(country_name), 'geometry']
        country_poly = country_map.values[0]
        return country_poly

 india_poly = country_polygon('india')
 point      = Point(76,23)

 point.within(india_poly) # I get True
 point.within(india_poly.boundary) # I get False
```

Why is that a point lies inside a polygon, but not inside its boundary?

Comment: Is `india_poly.boundary` a polygon, or a line geometry?

Comment: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.boundary

Comment: The `boundary` of a polygon is a LineString. So your point lies somewhere within the polygon, but not exactly on the boundary line. Actually, if it would be located exactly on the boundary, the point would not be "within" the polygon (that is the sometimes confusing definition of "within"). https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.within

Comment: Thanks. I was only looking at visualization of the boundary and made the mistake.